# The deleted certificate will be restored after rebooting. But why?

Tags: mac, keychain, certificate

I installed a file *.developerprofile. Then I went to the keychain and deleted 3 certificates (they were expired). Everything is OK. But deleted certificates appeared when I rebooted my Mac. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very good solutions, but it works for me. I deleted all profiles, certificates. Then I generated new profiles, certificates and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a possibly similar problem, related to a PPTP VPN and user certs.

Be sure to delete all old certificates from **each keychain** in Keychain Access. Also: be sure to choose "All Items" as the category.

In any case, I'm curious to hear whether you came up with a solution, so please remember to log any remarks on this page.

Comment: It didn't helped me.